# Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/activity_a

Tags: android

I just began android coding and I'm still learning from my mistakes. I use `WebView` to load internal html pages and I want to open another activity window which will be a `barcode scanner` by clicking a hyperlink on `webview`. However I get this error

`Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/activity_a://qrcodeactivity`

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="qrcodeactivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="activity_a" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

index.html

```
<a href="activity_a://qrcodeactivity">Activity A</a>
```

MyWebClient Java

```
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equals("activity_a://qrcodeactivity")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), qrcodeactivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true; // Handle By application itself
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            if (loader.equals("pull")) {
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
            } else if (loader.equals("dialog")) {
                if (!pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.show();
                }
            } else if (loader.equals("never")) {
                Log.d("WebView", "No Loader selected");
            }

            return true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        if (swipeContainer.isRefreshing()) {
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + getString(R.string.error_page));
    }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` has no idea what `activity_a://` is. Apparently, it is treating it as a relative reference, as if it were `activity_a/`.

Since you are using this in a `WebView`, there is no need to invent your own scheme. You are checking the entire URL in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

So, you could change the HTML to:

```
<a href="/qrcodeactivity">Activity A</a>
```

and change your `if` to match:

```
if (url.equals("file:///qrcodeactivity")) {
```

And, you can get rid of the `<intent-filter>` from your `<activity>`. Having that is dangerous, anyway, as you are indicating that any app on the device can start that activity, as an activity with an `<intent-filter>` is exported.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer. I did you changes however i'm still getting the same error.

file:///qrcodeactivity not found

Comment: @zontrakulla: Sorry, I forgot the scheme in the `if` test. See the updated answer. Basically, your `if` needs to match the URL that `WebView` generates.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.